# I would like to start sound editing, which applications should I use?

Tags: sound-editing

I would like to start sound editing, which applications should I use?

I'm planning editing sound(cut, remove noise, add remove effects) for mobile applications and to send to Adobe Premiere

Comment: Please do a little research before asking. We don't encourage questions that are purely based on recommendations. It's easy to find tools online, which you can evaluate and test. If you have a specific problem achieving something with one of these tools, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/) is quite good, free and open source.

It comes preloaded with a wide range of filters and effects and is compatible with, amongst others, VST plugins (i.e. as used by Cubase), if the built-in ones doesn't satisfy your needs.

I've used it for recording radio broadcasted concerts, transferring cassette tapes to CD/MP3 and editing recordings when I was out playing with my band (mainly EQ, compression and cutting).

Here's the official [feature list](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/about/features).

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend [Adobe Audition](http://www.adobe.com/products/audition.html). It has excellent waveform editing capabilities, and should integrate nicely with Premiere.

Comment: How does Audition compare with Pro Tools or Sony Vegas?

Comment: @Lèsemajesté From my (admittedly limited) experience, Audition is better for waveform editing, while Pro Tools is better for multitracking. As for Vegas, I've used it only briefly for video editing, so I can't say about its audio editing capabilities.